# SQL Server 2012 multiple triggers

Tags: sql, triggers, sql-update, sql-server-2012

Well, in SQL server 2012, I have a table which tracks the capacity of... well, items...

Basically, `Storage` table has `Capacity` and `Filled` columns, and `Filled` column needs to be updated every time  there is any change in the `Item` table, but it can not be higher than `Capacity` value or lower then "0". I have tried to put it all in just one trigger... I hope I am making any sense so far... This is what I have tried to do, and I have figured that trigger is only activated when INSERT occurs...

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[CapCheck]
ON [dbo].[Item]
AFTER INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Amount int
DECLARE @S_ID int

SELECT  @Amount = Amount, @S_ID = S_ID
FROM inserted

IF @Amount = NULL
BEGIN
     SELECT @Amount = -(Amount), @S_ID = S_ID
     FROM deleted
END

DECLARE @Filled int
DECLARE @Capacity int

SELECT @Filled = Filled, @Capacity = Capacity 
FROM Storage
WHERE S_ID = @S_ID

SET @Filled = @Filled + @Amount

IF @Capcaity < @Filled OR @Filled < 0
BEGIN
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    UPDATE Storage
    SET Filled = @Filled
    WHERE S_ID = @S_ID
END
END
```

Any advice is much appreciated, you guys are the best :D

Answer (score 0):

Your fundamental flaw is that you seem to expect the trigger to be fired **once per row** - this is **NOT** the case in SQL Server. Instead, the trigger fires **once per statement**, and the pseudo table `Inserted` might contain **multiple rows**.

Given that that table might contain multiple rows - which one do you expect will be selected here??

```
SELECT  @Amount = Amount, @S_ID = S_ID
FROM inserted
```

It's undefined - you might get the values from arbitrary rows in `Inserted`.

You need to rewrite your entire trigger with the knowledge the `Inserted` **WILL** contain multiple rows! You need to work with set-based operations - don't expect just a single row in `Inserted` !

Also: I would highly recommend to write **separate triggers** for each operation - have a trigger for `INSERT`, another for `DELETE` and a third for `UPDATE`. This will make the trigger code much easier (since you don't have to have many checks on what kind of operation you're dealing with).